# Definition of separable stochastic process. Which is the "intuition" behind such a definition?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, intuition, separable-spaces

Herebelow, I quote **Kuo (2006)**

> *Definition*: A stochastic process $X(t,\omega)$, $0\leq t\leq 1$, $\omega\in\Omega$ is called separable if there exist $\Omega_0$ with $P(\Omega_0)=1$ and a countable dense subset $S$ of $[0,1]$ such that for any closed set $F\subset\mathbb{R}$ and any open interval $I\subset [0,1]$, the set difference
> $$\bigg\{\omega\in\Omega; X(t,\omega)\in\ F, \forall \text{ } t\in I\cap S\bigg\}\backslash\bigg\{\omega\in\Omega; X(t,\omega)\in F,\forall \text{ }t\in I\bigg\}$$
> is a subset of the complement $\Omega_0^c$ of $\Omega_0$. The set $S$ is called a separating set.

First, isn't $\Omega_0^c=\emptyset$? 
Secondly, what does the fact that $S$ is a subset of the complement $\Omega_0^c$ of $\Omega_0$ mean? What does $S$ "separate"? From what? 
More generally, could you please explain the intuition behind such a definition, even in very rough terms? What is it useful for?

Comment: First, we do not necessarily have $\Omega_0^c =\varnothing$ (though it could be). What $P(\Omega_0) = 1$ is saying is that **almost every point** is in $\Omega_0$ (where almost everywhere is with respect to probability). This is a measure theoretic notion.

Comment: The intuition is that the trajectories of your process are "essentially" determined by a countable dense subset $S$. Essentially is heavily in quotes because it's saying that the set where it's not determined is a set of probability $0$ (or measure $0$ if that's okay to say).

Comment: @User203940 As to the first part, I understand what you mean. But why in many books do I read $$\Omega^c=\emptyset$$?

Comment: Well $\Omega$ is your whole space. This is saying $\Omega_0$ is some set so that $P(\Omega_0) = 1$.

Comment: Oh, ok, that's the point, perfect, thank you a lot. As to the main part of the question, following your reasoning, why so we define $S$ as a separating set? What does it "separate"? From what? @User203940

Comment: Ceterum censeo: posts containing "intuition" should be rejected automatically by MSE. It's something that can't be explained by definition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Separability means that the behavior of the process is essentially determined by its values on a countable ("separating") set. This is actually not a stochastic but rather an analytic notion. One may similarly define separability of a non-random function:

> $f\colon A\to B$ is separable, if there exists a countable dense subset $S\subset A$ with the property: for any closed $F\subset B$ and any open $I\subset A$, if $f(t)\in F$ for all $t\in I\cap S$ , then $f(t)\in F$ for all $t\in I$.

And then one may call a process separable if $X(\cdot,\omega)$ is separable for almost all $\omega\in \Omega$ (which is precisely the usual definition).

Concerning the term itself, it originates from "separable set/separable space", where it is also not very suitable: there is nothing being "separated" (see also a relevant discussion [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/51494/why-the-name-separable-space)).

Comment: How is definition you provide related to the fact $$\bigg\{\omega\in\Omega; X(t,\omega)\in\ F, \forall \text{ } t\in I\cap S\bigg\}\backslash\bigg\{\omega\in\Omega; X(t,\omega)\in F,\forall \text{ }t\in I\bigg\}$$ is a subset of the complement $\Omega_0^c$ of $\Omega_0$? I was interpreting such a fact as "Almost nowhere the set difference $$\bigg\{\omega\in\Omega; X(t,\omega)\in\ F, \forall \text{ } t\in I\cap S\bigg\}\backslash\bigg\{\omega\in\Omega; X(t,\omega)\in F,\forall \text{ }t\in I\bigg\}$$ exists", but I am pretty sure it is wrong. How is that related to your definition? @zhoraster

Comment: @Strictly_increasing, with the definition of separability of a function at hand, the definition from Kuo's book can be equivalently rewritten as "there exists $\Omega_0$ with $\mathrm P(\Omega_0) = 1$ such that for any $\omega\in \Omega_0$, $X(\cdot,\omega)$ is a separable function". Which is precisely what I wrote in my answer.

Comment: OK, I think I have grasped the meaning. Just one last fact: the statement I made in my previous comment, that is: "Almost nowhere the set difference $$\bigg\{\omega\in\Omega; X(t,\omega)\in\ F, \forall \text{ } t\in I\cap S\bigg\}\backslash\bigg\{\omega\in\Omega; X(t,\omega)\in F,\forall \text{ }t\in I\bigg\}$$ exists" is then wrong as an interpretation of Kuo's book words? If so, how could it be corrected and rearranged? Thank you a lot @zhoraster

Comment: This sentence is just synonimous.